# How to calculate eye rotation to look at a target with an arbitrary head rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to have a head that can have any rotation including being upside down or facing backwards. I want the eyes to attempt to look at a given location (can use the same rotation value for both eyes). I want to know the yaw (left-right) and pitch (up-down) values of the eyes. Eventually I'd clamp these (e.g. to -30 to 30 degrees).

So I need a float value for yaw and a value for pitch rather than just using LookAt to position the eyes. (or maybe it could use LookAt to generate those values?) So if the head was upside down and the target location was on the ground the eyes would be looking "upwards" (downwards from the point of view of the world) with a positive pitch value.

The input parameters would be head position, head rotation, and target position with an output of eye pitch (up-down) and yaw (left-right).

(The reason why I need yaw and pitch values is to move the eyes in a 2D texture of a face - I can't just use "LookAt")

About what I tried:

I couldn't figure out how to use vector and rotation type math to calculate the exact pitch and yaw for the eyes as they look towards the target location (the player) given that the head could be at any rotation.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of what you tried (reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and fix your question to SO standards (reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the eyes will be children of the head and you need those values as relative to the head rotation I think you could do something like e.g.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns clamped pith and yaw for the eye relative to the head rotation looking towards the target
/// </summary>
public static (float pitch, float yaw) GetEyeRotation(Transform eye, Transform head, Transform target)
{
    // desired look direction
    var direction = target.position - eye.position;
    // the according rotation as quaternion
    var desiredRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction, head.up);
    // as a local rotation relative to the head rotation
    var desiredRotationRelativeToHead = Quaternion.Inverse(head.rotation) * desiredRotation;
    // as euler angles
    var relativeEulers = desiredRotationRelativeToHead.eulerAngles;
    // fix values to be between -180 and 180
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (relativeEulers[i] < -180) relativeEulers[i] += 360;
        if (relativeEulers[i] > 180) relativeEulers[i] -= 360;
    }

    // now clamp
    relativeEulers.x = Mathf.Clamp(relativeEulers.x, -30, 30);
    relativeEulers.y = Mathf.Clamp(relativeEulers.y, -30, 30);

    return (relativeEulers.x, relativeEulers.y);
}
```

Comment: Hi it involves a decapitated head a bit like in Minecraft with 2D eye graphics (with greater texture resolution for the eye movement) that look towards the player so the eyes are not children of the head. The position of the eyes could be assumed to be the same as the position of the head. So I think the only parameters would be head position, head rotation (which use combined as "transform"), and target position. I'd use the yaw and pitch to calculate the 2D offset of the eye graphics. Having multiple outputs like that is interesting - I didn't know C sharp could do that!

Comment: Hi also I can't seem to get head.rotation.InverseTransformRotation(desiredRotation) to work.... could you just put the extra code in GetEyeRotation rather than calling InverseTransformRotation? Thanks

Comment: @LukeWenke removed the extensions ... not sure though if this is useful then .. I was assuming 3D objects and local orientation (relative to head) for the eyes

Comment: Thanks I got it to work. I had to multiply the yaw and pitch by -1 for some reason then I offset the 2D texture for the eyes (maybe the head model is initially rotated the wrong way). For some reason some of the heads won't update the eyes and it seems to be based on the initial rotation of the head.